# show that $c′(5)$ is orthogonal to $\nabla f(1,4,2).$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

I need some help here.

Let $f(x, y, z)$ be a differentiable function and suppose that $c(t)$ is a path which lies on
the surface $f(x, y, z) = 17.$ If $c(5) = <1, 4, 2>$ show that $c′(5)$ is orthogonal to $∇f(1,4,2).$

Comment: is that not the definition of $\nabla f?$

Comment: Do I just restate the definition?

Comment: i can't see what else you can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ constant imply

$0=\dfrac{f(c(t))}{dt}=\nabla f(c(t))\cdot{c'(t)}$

Comment: that's it? I was thinking that but it seems so simple and the question is from an exam review sheet